# Assign LWP command to Perl variable

Tags: perl, lwp

The network guys at my work are applying upgrades and patches that sometimes cause my LWP to error out with http status 500.

I have about 50 Perl apps with the below line of code.  Instead of changing all 50 apps each time security protocols change, I'd like to use a variable.  However, I can't seem to hit on the right way to assign the LWP to a variable.

Current code that works:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0 });
```

Want to do this, but keep getting errors:

```
my $lwp = "LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0 })";
my $ua = $lwp;
```

I plan to put the lwp string in a file or a module, but coded the above for illustrative purposes.

Any advice on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Tried these, but they did not work:

```
my $ua = <$LWP>;
my $ua =  eval "\$$LWP";
my $ua = ${$LWP}; `
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Explain _"each time security protocols change"_ -- what kinds of changes are you expecting; also _"keep getting errors"_ -- what errors are in the server logs?

Comment: Why don't you just make a `sub get_lwp { return LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0 }); }` and then call that each time you need it?

Comment: @Robert And then such a sub can go into a module etc.  Absolutely no need to go to `eval`.  This is a good and valid answer I think, even as the question is a little messy, why not post it as such?

Comment: @zdim Done! I thought it was too simple.

Comment: @Robert "_too simple_" -- Being simple need not rob it of usefulness and other qualities :)

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't go with any `eval` based approach. The code you `eval` is a String, so you won't get syntax highlighting in your editor, you cannot run `perl -c` to check it, and there is just no point to `eval`.

A simpler approach would be to just define a function in a module, e.g., `UserAgentMaker.pm` that you can `use` and call:

```perl
package UserAgentMaker;

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

sub get_lwp {
    return LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0 });
} 

1;
```

Then use it:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use UserAgentMaker;

my $ua = UserAgentMaker::get_lwp();
# use $ua
```

You can also extend this and create different `get_lwp` functions if clients need to create them with different options, like a `get_legacy_lwp`, get `get_tls_1_1_lwp` and whatever else you need.

You may need to pass `-I` to `perl` so that Perl finds your module. For example, if both are in the same directory:

```bash
perl -I. example.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation for LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP), you'll see that it recognises an environment variable called `PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME` to set the default value for `verify_hostname`.

So you could just remove the `verify_hostname` option from all of your calls to `LWP::UserAgent->new()` and arrange to have the environment variable set correctly before running your application.